# Convert Hex to Decimal when no datatype can hold the full number

Tags: c, algorithm, bignum, pic

I am working with a PIC microprocessor, in C. It's a 16F, so it can't hold integers larger than 32bits (unsigned `int32` is the largest datasize available)

From a reader, I receive a 5 byte ID code. To transmit it, I have to encoded to BCD, digit by digit. I can't sprint it to a string, as it is larger that the data size, and can't process it. I can't divide it because no operation is defined for it.

I can't figure out any solution possible, does anyone have dealt with this before?

EDIT:

I receive the number in a series of 5 bytes:

> FF-FF-FF-FF-FF

I need to convert it to decimal

> 0123456789012

(13 digits, length of 256^5 in decimal) to send it through RS232. The second function (Take the ASCII, and send it) I already have it working, but I need the string representation of the full number before I can do anything with it.

Comment: Please be more specific... How do you receive the 5 bytes ? As an array of unsigned char ?
What is then the format you need to transmit it ?

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing: if I understand correctly, you receive a 5 bytes long array, representing an ID. This ID has not been encoded in anyway, and is simply a 5*8 bits long int, right ? And you what it to be converted to an decimel ascii representation of that ID, correct ? I ask because you mention BCD, and I don't understand where it's used ? Is the ID encoded in BCD when received ?

Comment: No, I have to output it in BCD, therefore I need the string representation of the decimal number (the int version is not enough as I have to go digit by digit to send it) I need to convert the 5 byte Id representation (5 unsigned 8 bit) to send the whole number. (The recipient can convert to hex that number and get the original 5 bytes)

Comment: OK, got it. I might have an idea, I'll try posting some sample code ;)

Comment: This is a fun question, but it didn't get very many veiws, that's a shame.  So many people say "just use a library" that they never consider how to actually do something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have 32 bit arithmetic: 2**24 = 16777216, so taking x as the most significant 2 bytes and y as the least significant 3:

```
  (16777216 * x + y) / 1000 
= (16777000 * x + 216 * x + y) / 1000
= 16777 * x + (216 * x + y) / 1000
```

The first term can be calculated in 32 bits without overflow (since `x < 2**16`).
The second term can also be calculated without overflow (since `x < 2**16` and `y < 2**24`).

This is basically long division in base `2**24` of a 2-digit value, but with terms pre-calculated knowing that the divisor is 1000. One thousand is chosen because it's the least power of 10 greater than `2**8`.

So, first compute the lowest three digits, use the fact that `(2**32) % 1000 == 296`. So this time we'll take x as the highest byte and y as the low 4 bytes

```
((2**32) * x + y) % 1000 = ((2**32) * x) % 1000 + y % 1000 (modulo 1000)
                         = (296 * x) % 1000 + y % 1000     (modulo 1000)
((2**32) * x + y) % 1000 = ((296 * x) % 1000 + y % 1000) % 1000
```

Then divide the original number by 1000 using the formula above. Then you're safely into 32 bit territory and can churn out the remaining digits using the normal loop.

Btw, I'd check the results if I were you: I haven't tested this and it's possible I've made an error somewhere. It should be easy to compare against the results of bcd conversions done using the usual means in a 64-bit integer on a PC.

Comment: Nice idea, I just need to wrap my mind around how to adapt it to C.

Comment: With your clarification, you are my new math hero.

Comment: I got the first 10 digits using the above formula, but I don't get it how to modify it to get the modulo of it. What am I missing here?

Comment: I've explained further and tidied up a bit, hope that helps.

Comment: I've tested the formulas in a PC and they work well. Bit twiddling is still magic to me, I am afraid. Thanks!

Comment: Just a follow up. I am taking an Elementary Algebra course at college and NOW, everything makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, is implement addition and multiplication for numbers coded as a string (sort of BigNum). That way, you can sprintf the most significant byte of your ID to a string "A", multiply it with the string "4294967296" (256^4) giving you string "B", sprintf the 4 least significant bytes of your ID in another string "C", and finally adding "B" and "C".

It's not very sexy, especially on a micro-controller, but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

The PIC16F does not have a hardware multiply or divide unit, so unless you are multiplying or dividing by a power of 2, it is taxing to the processor.  Here is a routine that does a BCD on a 32 bit number and doesn't require division or multiplication.  You could adapt this to a 5 byte number by doing it in chunks.

void BCD32(int32u numIn)
{
    int8u digit = 0;

```
while (numIn >= 1000000000)
{
    numIn -= 1000000000;
    digit++;
}    
debug[0] = digit + 48;   
digit = 0;
while (numIn >= 100000000)
{
    numIn -= 100000000;
    digit++;
}    
debug[1] = digit + 48;            
digit = 0;
while (numIn >= 10000000)
{
    numIn -= 10000000;
    digit++;
}    
debug[2] = digit + 48;            
digit = 0;
while (numIn >= 1000000)
{
    numIn -= 1000000;
    digit++;
}    
debug[3] = digit + 48;            
digit = 0;
while (numIn >= 100000)
{
    numIn -= 100000;
    digit++;
}    
debug[4] = digit + 48;            
digit = 0;
while (numIn >= 10000)
{
    numIn -= 10000;
    digit++;
}
debug[5] = digit + 48;        
digit = 0;
while (numIn >= 1000)
{
    numIn -= 1000;
    digit++;
}
debug[6] = digit + 48;    
digit = 0;    
while (numIn >= 100)
{
    numIn -= 100;
    digit++;
}
debug[7] = digit + 48;

digit = 0;
while (numIn >= 10)
{
    numIn -= 10;
    digit++;
}
debug[8] = digit + 48;

digit = 0;
while (numIn >= 1)
{
    numIn -= 1;
    digit++;
}
debug[9] = digit + 48;    
debug[10] = CARRIAGE_RETURN;
debug[11] = NEW_LINE_FEED;
SendUart(12);
```

}

Comment: I'll have this into account if I need performance on the BCD routines. For now, I am just doing a sprintf into a char array. But the main concern was the bytes-to-string conversion carried out byonebyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can always "sprintf" it to a string manually yourself. go over the data byte after byte and convert it to a numerical string by appending individual characters.

Comment: Mmm, no. If I do that, I would only be appending decimals. I need to grab the full hex number (the appended 0-F chars) and convert the whole thing to decimal. The results vary wildly as it is 16^n each digit.

Answer (score 0):

The core of this problem I would say is one of "long division" to convert to decimal.  Not entirely unlike long division you learned in grade school, though with binary numbers, long division is much simpler.  But its still a lot of work.

try:
[http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55951.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20180125125303/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55951.html)

You will have to implement your own multi-byte subtraction and shift routines.

Comment: Actually you can do this using only shifts and +3 operations.  Long division is a brute force method.