# Convert Decimal to Hex when no datatype can hold the full number

Tags: bit-manipulation, bignum, pic

This is an almost exact duplicate of my own question a few weeks ago.

[Convert Hex to Decimal when no datatype can hold the full number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143302/convert-hex-to-decimal-when-no-datatype-can-hold-the-full-number)

This time, it is the reverse. I have the number (in a handy null terminated string) and I need the bytes that make this number. However, I am working in a 32 bits architecture for a micro controller, therefore I don't have the possibility of using the atoi, as the number is larger than 32 bits.

Does anyone have an idea on how to reverse the algorithm provided in the first link, as to get back the original result? My modulo arithmetic skills are failing me.

Quick Example: **155.207.231.135** to **0x[24][23][12][66][9F]** (the brackets separate the bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to BigInt division.

```
a = atoi of lower 7 decimal digits
b = atoi of remaining upper decimal digits


for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    a += 10000000 * (b % 256);
    b /= 256;
    Result[i] = a % 256;
    a /= 256;
}
```

Comment: I don't get why the a%32, when a byte array can hold up to a%256

Comment: You are correct, I had apparently not had sufficient caffeine when I posted, fixed :)

Comment: Although come to think of it, that starts presenting an overflow issue. Have to limit it to 7 decimal digits to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine now.

Only correction I have to make is the byte array is reversed. You could change the Result[i] to Result[4-i] to get them in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need assembler for this one. Pseudocode:

```
int low = 0 // lower 32 bit
int high = 0 // higher 32 bit

for (int i=0; i<string.length(); i++) {
    int digit = string.get(i) - '0';
    int a = low;
    int b = high;
    a <<= 1; b += overflow;             // *2
    a <<= 1; b += overflow;             // *4
    a += low; b += overflow; b += high; // *5
    a <<= 1; b += overflow;             // *10
    a += digit; b += overflow;          // +digit
    low = a; high = b;
}
```

So basically, you create a 64bit register using two 32bit ints. For each loop, you:

```
    value *= 10 + digit;
```

Afterwards, you only need to skip the 0 bytes at the beginning of the resulting value to get the bytes you seek.

Comment: I don't get what "overflow" is supposed to be.

Comment: Every CPU has an overflow or carry bit that is set when the last operation didn't fit into the involved data types. If you have a byte with the value 0xff and you shift that right once, the carry bit will be set (since the topmost bit was set) and the byte will be 0xfe.

Comment: Often, you have "ADDC" (add with carry), so you could "ROR a; AADC #0, b;" or there is a branch: "ROR a; BCC #label; ADD #1, b; #label" so the ADD is skipped if the carry bit is not set.

Comment: Sorry, I do not fully understand assembly yet, I code in C. However, in my compiler, I have a function called shift_right (and left) which returns me the value popped during the operation. I think it could be analogous to what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Analogous to the overflow bit (as I can't seem to find this register it in my micro controller datasheet)

Comment: Basically, this code emulates a 64bit "multiply by 10". Maybe your library already contains a 64bit multiply.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the string from left to right, multiplying the previous result by ten and adding the digit.

Here's some code in C# to show the concept. First two methods to to math on an array:

```
static void Mul(byte[] data, int num) {
   int n = 0;
   for (int i = data.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      n += (int)data[i] * num;
      data[i] = (byte)n;
      n >>= 8;
   }
}

static void Add(byte[] data, int num) {
   for (int i = data.Length - 1; num > 0; i-- ) {
      num += (int)data[i];
      data[i] = (byte)num;
      num >>= 8;
   }
}
```

Then you just do:

```
string s = "155207231135";
byte[] result = new byte[16];
foreach (char c in s) {
   Mul(result, 10);
   Add(result, c - '0');
}
```

The result is in the `result` array, padded with zero bytes to the left.

It shouldn't bee to hard to translate to C... :)